# Преобразуйте файл Edifact в объекты Java

Tags: java

так как я не смог найти непротиворечивую информацию в английской версии, я подумал, может быть, я смогу найти ее на русском языке. У меня есть файл, который поддерживает версию Edifact UNOA 4. И мне нужно преобразовать данные в этом файле в мои классы моделей в java. Но я не смог найти ни одного необходимого материала. Не могли бы вы показать мне документ или код о том, как это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/276925/